# How to exclude test classes form Coverage Analysis using Jacoco

Tags: java, jacoco, sonarcloud

I have some test to check my code. I have generated my report in sonarcloud but I have a problem: The coverage percentage takes into account also the test classes, that are obviously uncovered by other test. Is there any option just to take into account all the classes but the test ones??

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would not adapt Jacoco, but you can exclude files from coverage report within sonarqube/sonarcloud with the `sonar.coverage.exclusions` property, where you can eg. specify a pattern like `**/*Test.java` to exlude all java files ending with `Test`.

Additionally you could also set this up within the UI, represented on the following screenshot:

[image: Settings in the UI]

Sidenote: i would inspect the sonar configuration, for me it looks like that test code is provided as normal sources to sonar. This would create such an topic, but normally sonar has an own property to configure test code. see [analysis parameters documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/) for further details or if you use gradle or maven plugins, check the respective documentation on how to organize the source code.